# Javascript Filereader sort by name

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, input

i'm trying to list my image preuploader sort by name but got some issues.i have dozen image with name img001 - img100 but when i input that the result show the files sort by image size. here is my code

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>generate nama ikan</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <h1>Nama Ikan</h1>
                  <input id="ingambar" type="file" multiple />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="content">
                      <br />
                        <table class="table">
                          <thead>
                            <th>gambar</th><th>nama</th>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody></tbody>
                        </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
    $('#ingambar').change(function () {
        for (var i=0, len = this.files.length; i < len; i++) {
            (function (j, self) {
                var reader = new FileReader()
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('tbody').append('<tr><td><img width="100px" src="' + e.target.result + '"></td><input class="form-control" type="text" value="' + self.files[j].name.slice(0, -4) + '" name="namaikan[]" disabled/></td></tr>')
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(self.files[j])
            })(i, this);
        }
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

can someone show me how to get it done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can `sort()` the table rows after you append a new one, based on the value of the `input` contained within the row. Try this:

```js
$('#ingambar').change(function() {
  for (var i = 0, len = this.files.length; i < len; i++) {
    (function(j, self) {
      var reader = new FileReader()
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('tbody').append('<tr><td><img width="100px" src="' + e.target.result + '"></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" value="' + self.files[j].name.slice(0, -4) + '" name="namaikan[]" disabled/></td></tr>');
        sortFiles();
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(self.files[j])
    })(i, this);
  }
});

function sortFiles() {
  $('.table tbody tr').sort(function(a, b) {
    var $a = $(a).find('input'),
      $b = $(b).find('input');
    return $a.val().localeCompare($b.val());
  }).appendTo('.table tbody');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>Nama Ikan</h1>
        <input id="ingambar" type="file" multiple />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="content">
          <br />
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <th>gambar</th>
              <th>nama</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can sort using javascripts Array build in function using a custom sort function with localeCompare. Inserting the following right before the for-loop should do what you want.

```js
this.files.sort((fileA, fileB) => fileA.name.localeCompare(fileB.name));
```

Providing that `this.files` is an array of files having a *name* attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of displaying the images as you read them, you could instead put them all i an array with the same for loop. Then sort the new array with a sort function. And then you just run through the array and display them. Works for me!